# failed to invoke procedure in APOC NLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Im trying to run this code & every time I get the same error. I tried both google API and Azure but both return similar error.

MATCH (a:Article)
CALL apoc.nlp.gcp.entities.graph(a, {
key: $apiKey,
nodeProperty: "body",
writeRelationshipType: "ENTITY"
})
YIELD graph AS g
RETURN g;

Error msg:
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.nlp.gcp.entities.graph`: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Plus, I manually added the APOC nlp jar package to my APOC plugin folder. Any solution would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have pasted the JAR file in the `plugins` directory for your database, please make sure that in the configuration file present in the `conf` directory of your database, the following setting is present:

`dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*`

Once you do this, then your library should be available to use, also make sure that if the following setting is present:

`dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*`

then `apoc.nlp.*` is also part of it.

The first setting basically allows the mentioned procedures full access to the database, and the second property is used only when you need to load a subset of a large library.

Also, make sure that the `Executable JAR file` is directly within the `plugins` directory, there is no requirement of creating a separate directory for `APOC`.  I am using neo4j 3.5, and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response! this " dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.* " was already present in the setting file & I also added the dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.* manually but still throws error. 'There is no procedure with the name `apoc.nlp.azure.entities.stream` . When I call apoc.nlp the autocomplete doesn't return anything nlp related. Also all plugging are at the same initial folder I did not added any new folder just pasted the apoc-nlp-dependencies.jar ...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with downgrading the neo4j DB from 4.4 to 4.0!